# Amazon Cognito: PreSignUp_SignUp Lambda Trigger Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

How do I access the user attributes and username of a user created by adminCreateUser API inside of Lambda Function. I know the event sample for normal signup is:

```
  {
      "version": 1,
      "triggerSource": "PreSignUp_SignUp",
      "region": "<region>",
      "userPoolId": "<userPoolId>",
      "userName": "<userName>",
      "callerContext": {
          "awsSdk": "<calling aws sdk with version>",
          "clientId": "<apps client id>",
          ...
      },
      "request": {
          "userAttributes": {
              "email": "<email>",
              "phone_number": "<phone_number>",
              ...
           },
          "validationData": {
              "k1": "v1",
              "k2": "v2",
              ...
           }
      },
      "response": {
          "autoConfirmUser": false
      }
}
```

But it seems the event format is different for the adminCreateUser approach.